# About NullPointer Exception in Arraylist

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

```
List<PrcSubList> listSl = new ArrayList<PrcSubList>();

if (listSl == null || listSl.size() == 0) {
     PrcSubList subListAdd=coreService.addSubListByAddAlert(childSub);

     System.out.println("sublist after insert db :" + subListAdd.getName());

     listSl.add(subListAdd);

     System.out.println(listSl.size() +" sublist after insert list:" + listSl.get(0).getName());

}
```

Ouput with first System.out.println("sublist after insert db :" + subListAdd.getName());

> sublist after insert db :SYSTEM_ALERT_12312313

### Problem

But i have NullPointerException with 2nd

```
System.out.println(listSl.size() +" sublist after insert list:" + listSl.get(0).getName());
```

Can you help me!

Comment: Your `subListAdd` must be null.

Comment: There are only two relevant objects in your code, `listS1` and `subListAdd`, and neither of them can be `null`, otherwise you would be getting an NPE sooner. Is this all your code? Can you just print those two objects?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Your `subListAdd` is `null`.

Check this code:

```
PrcSubList subListAdd=coreService.addSubListByAddAlert(childSub);
```

The error is thrown when you try to get the name of that element when it is appearantly `null`:

```
listSl.get(0).getName()
         ^
         calling getName() on null objects throws you that exception
```

---

Also, there is something wrong with this line:

```
if (listSl == null || listSl.size() == 0) {
```

The `== null` is non needed check because you instantiate the list above. Also, the size is equal to zero because of the same reason.

Comment: If `subListAdd` is `null` , how can `subListAdd.getName()` not be a NPE

Comment: Hi @darijan
result subListAdd in my code not null because
System.out.println("sublist after insert db :" + subListAdd.getName());
return sublist after insert db :SYSTEM_ALERT_12312313 !